# I can't mount windows folder in centos through mount -t cifs

Tags: centos, mount, cifs, centos8

everyone!

I have windows folder. This folder is available from my windows 10 OS.
At the server with Centos 8 I did:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/sbsp
sudo mount -t cifs //bk.local/BurgerKing/NetDisks/K/Бухгалтерия/Сбер_Спасибо_Отчет /mnt/sbsp -o user=user1,iocharset=utf8,"pass=12345",uid=bk_root,gid=bk_root
```

I recieved output:

```
mount error(2): No such file or directory
```

In dmesg:

```
[1457351.175943] CIFS: Attempting to mount \\bk.local\BurgerKing
[1457351.205772] CIFS: VFS:  BAD_NETWORK_NAME: \\bk.local\BurgerKing
[1457351.307879] CIFS: VFS:  BAD_NETWORK_NAME: \\bk.local\NetDisk
[1457351.317199] CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -2
```

In journalctl the same as dmesg.

I can mount another folder from another windows server, but unfortunately I can't make the same with this. Please help, what is wrong?

Comment: What does `smbclient -L <host>` give?

Comment: smbclient -L bk.local -U svc-dwh-etl
Enter SAMBA\svc-dwh-etl's password:

        Sharename       Type      Comment
        ---------       ----      -------
        ADMIN$          Disk      Remote Admin
        C$              Disk      Default share
        IPC$            IPC       Remote IPC
        NETLOGON        Disk      Logon server share
        SYSVOL          Disk      Logon server share
SMB1 disabled -- no workgroup available